# ACL: giving - - - permissions for the owner of the file

Tags: linux, file-permissions, access-control-list, setfacl

At the beginning, I have these permissions for a file:

```
# file: jar
# owner: my_user
# group: my_user
user::rw-
group::rw-
other::r--
```

After running this:

```
setfacl -m u:my_user:--- jar
```

and get this permissións:

```
# file: foobar
# owner: my_user
# group: my_user
user::rw-
user:my_user:---
group::rw-
mask::rw-
other::r--
```

I expected `my_user` not to have permissión to read (for example) this file, but it has..

Answer (score 3):

ACLs differentiate between `ACL_USER` (the line `user::rw-`), which is the owner of the file just like without ACLs and `ACL_USER_OBJ` (the line `user:my_user:---`), which are additional permission sets for users. In case of an `ACL_USER_OBJ` that is the same as the file owner `ACL_USER`, the latter will have higher priority.

So, in your case `user::rw-` overrides `user:my_user:---`.

Just use classic `chmod`.

Comment: I think you got the names backward: `ACL_USER_OBJ` is for the file owner, and `ACL_USER` entries are for additional users. See [man acl](https://linux.die.net/man/5/acl)